# Input and Output Redirection

Tags: c, linux

So, like how the Linux terminal works.

If I do something like `ls -l` and type in the command `ls -l > hello.txt`, it writes whatever was in `ls -l` to `hello.txt`.

I'm making a terminal of my own and I'm trying to make it so that when a user types in that same command `ls -l > asdf.txt` that it writes out ls -l to whatever text file that user inputs.

So here is what I have. My mini-terminal shell works already.

```
FILE *fp
if (strcmp(args[1], ">") == 0) {
    fp = freopen(args[2], "w+", stdout);
}
fclose(fp);
```

How would I go to outputting whatever is in the 0th argument into the text file? So like, `w > hello.txt` would output into `hello.txt`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a file with C in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008267/how-to-write-a-file-with-c-in-linux)

Comment: actually it outputs the output of the command "ls -l" into the file

Comment: @Pooya Yeah. That's what I meant to say.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How to execute a command and write its output to a file, in C?

Comment: @JonnyHenly Yeah. Kind of confused on how to start it. Been trying to code it for a few minutes now, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Comment: The [GNU C Manual has a chapter on process creation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Processes.html#Processes) that might be useful.

Comment: This is operating system specific. On Linux, you could use `dup2` in the child process (between `fork` and `exec`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are correct with your arguments (args) you can do the following:

```
char buffer [1024];
FILE *fp
if (strcmp(args[1], ">") == 0) {
    fp = freopen(args[2], "w+", stdout);
} else {return; }

FILE *cmd;
cmd = popen(args[0],"r");
if(cmd == NULL)
  return;

while (fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer)-1,cmd)!=NULL)
{
   fprintf(fp,"%s",buffer);
}

fclose(fp);
pclose(cmd);
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you execute the ls command, you can check out popen, it will run the command, and then returns a FILE, which you can read the output of the command from, and then you could write the output into the file for redirection.
For example:

```
FILE *fin = popen("/bin/ls -l", "r");
if (!fp) { ... //handle error }
FILE *fout = freopen(args[2], "w", stdout);
char c;
while ((c = fgetc(fin)) != EOF) {
    fputc(c, fout);
}
pclose(fin);
fclose(fout);
```